# Uncaught TypeError: Property 'setCurrency' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: jquery, conflict, prestashop

I am getting the following jquery error: "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'setCurrency' of object [object Object] is not a function" which I cannot get my head around. The error happens when you try and change the currency: http://aaronjpitts.com/temp/petiteannee

The setCurrency function is defined as:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    function setCurrency(id_currency)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
            url: baseDir + 'index.php' + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
            data: 'controller=change-currency&id_currency='+ parseInt(id_currency),
            success: function(msg)
            {
                location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

I have had to wrap some of my functions in the jquery noconflict function to get things working
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($)

I'm sure this has something to do with the error. Can anyone see how this error is being generated? The site is built on prestashop.

Many thanks

Comment: We need to see your code to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Where is defined the "setCurrency" function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `setCurrency` declaration outside of document ready.

As shown in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zhz2C/1) example, functions declarated inside of document ready are not found by onclick references.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function test1(x) {
        // I'm not working
    }

});

function test2(y) {
    // I am working!
    console.log(y);

}
```

Comment: This will create a global variable and pollute the global namespace, especially if you have to do this many times. You can avoid this by  assigning functionality to buttons using event handlers: `$('#example-button).on('click', function(){ setCurrency('the_currency_id'); });` Docs on this [here](http://devdocs.io/jquery/on).

Comment: off course, yours is a better design but the OP present a code where he was using onclick.